# What is the difference between rdoc and md?

Tags: ruby, github, markdown

Standard ruby on rails project has README.rdoc.
Many github rails projects have README.md.

What is the difference?

Comment: This a strange question. What do you *actually* want to know? They are just different markup languages. One used rdoc, the other markdown.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Answer fragment from another deleted Stack Overflow question by [kiddorails](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1376448/kiddorails):

> RDoc is a fantastic tool which enables the automatic generation of formatted HTML containing our documented code.
>
> For example, most of gems on RubyGems fetch documentation and compiles them to give the resultant rdoc.

If your project doesn't have README.md, GitHub may parse README.rdoc to display details. If it has both, it will use README.md, silently ignoring rdoc. I usually have both, README.md for Github, and README.rdoc for RDoc documentation on RubyGems.

Comment: You should always reference [the source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19478758/1039893)

Comment: When considering rdoc it is worth also taking a look at [YARD](http://yardoc.org), which extends rdoc in some very powerful ways.

Comment: If this is plagiarism, it would be great if someone would cite the source in the answer and flag these comments for obsolescence. Also, same answers indicate these questions could be dupes, so consider flagging for that as well.

Answer (score 6):

[RDoc](http://rdoc.sourceforge.net/) - is a RubyGem which produces HTML and command-line documentation for Ruby projects. RDoc includes the rdoc and ri tools for generating and displaying documentation from the command-line.

[Digging Deeper Rdoc](https://github.com/rdoc/rdoc)

[Markdown also known as md](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) is a plain text formatting syntax[5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) designed so that it can optionally be converted to HTML using a tool by the same name. Markdown is popularly used as format for readme files, or for writing messages in online discussion forums, or in text editors for the quick creation of rich text documents.

[Github's Markdown](http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/)

[Github's Markdown basics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown)

Answer (score 2):

RDoc is a markup language. Markdown is a different markup language. HTML is yet another markup language. Any of those can be used to markup text, and all of those are supported by various code-browsing tools including but not limited to GitHub.